# Resource in Users.Undelete in AdminDirectory API (Google-Apps-Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

```
AdminDirectory.Users.undelete(resource, userKey)
```

UserKey is the UserID/UserKey. Not sure what is the resource here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The only parameter required by [Directory API: Users: undelete](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/undelete) is `orgUnitPath`.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation:

> In the request body, supply data with the following structure:

```json
{
  "orgUnitPath": string
}
```

Where the `orgUnitPath` is the path to the Organizationan unit you wish to restore the user to. You can get a list of your Organizational units from the [`Orgunits: list`]9v) method of the same API.

The `orgUnitPath` parameter needs to be preceded with a `/`, as per the [resource representation documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits#resource-representations) on Orgunits:

> **orgUnitPath**: The full path to the organizational unit. The `orgUnitPath` is a derived property. When listed, it is derived from `parentOrgunitPath` and organizational unit's `name`. For example, for an organizational unit named `'apps'` under parent organization `'/engineering'`, the `orgUnitPath` is `'/engineering/apps'`. In order to edit an `orgUnitPath`, either update the name of the organization or the `parentOrgunitPath`.

So as for this example, you would need to provide the following resource:

```json
{
  "orgUnitPath": "/engineering/apps"
}
```

#### Something to remember:

When undeleting a user, unlike the `delete` method, ***you can not specify their email address in the `userKey` field to restore them.*** This is mentioned in the `undelete` documentation:

> `userKey`: Identifies the user in the API request. **The value must be the user's unique user ID.**

#### Code Example:

```js
function undeleteUser() {
  AdminDirectory.Users.undelete(
    {
      orgUnitPath: '/My-Org-Unit-Path'
    }, 
    '21-character-unique-user-id'
  );
}
```

The unique user ID can be obtained from a `Users: list` request.

#### References:

- [Directory API - `Users: undelete`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/undelete)
- [Orgunits - Resource Representation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits#resource-representations)
- [Directory API - `Users: list`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list)